# Static constructor in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, wpf-controls

I am rewriting a C# class in VB.NET. The C# class has a static constructor in it:

```
static Class()
{
    ...
}
```

which, through the call stack, I found is called by the main window's InitializeComponent() method. Everywhere I've looked has told me that the corresponding static constructor in VB.NET is just:

```
Shared Sub New()
    ...
End Sub
```

But this method is never invoked. Am I creating my VB.NET static constructor right? Is it likely something else that has nothing to do with my static constructor?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The static constructor is triggered by the first of the following events to occur within an [application domain](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_Domain).

1. An instance of that class is created
2. Any of the static members of that
   class is accessed/referenced.

Comment: Yeah, you were right.  They were creating a temporary class to invoke the static trigger.